# cannot change focus to slider in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, focus

I have a function that changes focus whenever a user presses enter.  This function works great on most pages, but now I have a page with 1 select and 2 sliders (jqueryui).  When I press enter, focus will not change to a slider.  A console.log statements show me that my select is returning the correct array of elements:

```
0: select#field_odometerunitsselect
1: div#field_fuelquantityrangeslider.ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all
2: div#field_fueldistancerangeslider.ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all
```

and my javascript is correctly changing to the next element in the array (in this case 1):

```
$('#'+inputs.eq(nextinput).id).focus().select();
```

Can someone tell me why the line above will not change focus to the slider?

To further analyze, I tried manually setting focus with this line

```
$('#field_fuelquantityrangeslider').focus();
```

and it too fails.  So it's not a code problem, it's a slider thing.  How does one set focus to a slider?

Answer (score 3):

You need to target the slider handle (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692745/786999):

```
$('#field_fuelquantityrangeslider .ui-slider-handle').focus();
```