# How to focus on a range slider using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rangeslider

I would like to be able to focus on an input element of the type '*range*', in other words, the default slider, so that the slider could be dragged without the user actually clicking on it. 
The obvious solution would be to just use `sliderelement.focus()`. 
This however doesn't work. 
I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692198/focus-on-slider-after-submitting-form-with-slider/13692745#13692745) that the reason for this, is that I have to call this method on the handle of the slider. 
The class of the slider handle should be '*ui-slider-handle*'.
But for some reason `document.querySelector('.ui-slider-handle')` returns `null`.
The weird part is that this **does work with JQuery** when I use `$('.ui-slider-handle')`.
I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1qy0t9x/18/) to clarify my problem. I would like to solve this using only Javascript.

--- edit ---
Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my explanation. The class `ui-slider-handle` is not a custom class I added to the slider handle, since I cannot access the handle. I expected this to be the default class based on the answer I found (which I stated earlier).

Comment: What's wrong with jQuery?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, but I want to make my project in pure Javascript. Even if I decided to use it, I still would like to know why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle, the querySelector is correct.

Your jQuery will always return true like that though.

For example change `var handle2 = document.querySelector('.ui-slider-handle');` to a made up class like `var handle2 = document.querySelector('.ui-slider-handlesdfsdfsdfsdf');` and it returns true.

If you want to check if an element exists you can use .length.

So just add .length to your selector and they will both return false.

```
var handle1 = $('.ui-slider-handle').length;
var handle2 = document.querySelector('.ui-slider-handle');

$('#1').html('JQuery, handle found: ' + (handle1 ? 'true' : 'false'))
$('#2').html('Javascript, handle found: ' + (handle2 ? 'true' : 'false'))
```

---

**To put focus on the range element simply use `.focus()`.**

Here is an example.  Use the buttons and your arrow keys to see that it is gaining/losing focus on the element.

```js
function getFocus() {
  document.getElementById("myRange").focus();
}

function loseFocus() {
  document.getElementById("myRange").blur();
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="myRange" value="50">

<p>Click the buttons below to give focus and/or remove focus from the slider control.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="getFocus()">Get focus</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loseFocus()">Lose focus</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, my bad. So if that is the case, I suppose there is no way to select the handle element of the slider?

Comment: document.querySelector('.ui-slider-handle').focus() should work

Comment: This is actually kind of the problem. I thought this as well but, unfortunately, since `document.querySelector('.ui-slider-handle')` returns null, it would throw an error.

Comment: For clarification in the case my question was misleading: '.ui-slider-handle' is not a custom made class. It is the method I tried based on the other answer I found on SO (which does not seem to work). I will update my question.

Comment: I am a bit confused but I made a working example to show you how simple it is to gain focus on range input.

Comment: I guess I was searching it too far, I already tried this approach but was expecting a visible change if the slider would be focussed. The arrow keys seem to be the only way to notice. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem.  Visually focus could have a visual effect depending on the site's CSS.